# How to reach multi-nested (by *ngFor) formControl for validation in ReactiveForms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have to create reusable dynamic form with validation.
I pass custom form template structure with the `FormControl`'s attribute values from `.ts` file and build the form with the help of `*ngFor` and `ngSwitch` For styling pourposes in the main `FormGroup` I put every 3 input fields into a new `FormGroup` using `*ngFor`. I have a `div` with the validation message, and trying to toggle visisbility using `*ngIf` with the `FormGroup` class' `get` method. 
The problem is I can't figure out the path to the desired control.

```
<form [formGroup]="dynamicFilterFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-content">
        <div class="form-row" *ngFor="let formRow of filterFormTemplate.formGroupArray" formGroupName="{{formRow.formGroupName}}">
            <div class="form-element" *ngFor="let formElem of formRow.formControls">
                <div [ngSwitch]="formElem.type">
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <label>{{formElem.label}}</label>
                            <input type="text" formControlName="{{formElem.name}}" pInputText/>
                            <div class="form-validation-text" *ngIf="!dynamicFilterFormGroup.get(formRow.formGroupName.formElem.name).valid && dynamicFilterFormGroup.get(formRow.formGroupName.formElem.name).touched">{{ 'formElem.validationText' | lang }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'number'">
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <label>{{formElem.label}}</label>
                            <input type="number" formControlName="{{formElem.name}}" pInputText/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="form-element" pButton type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" label="{{ 'button_search' | lang}}"></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

So the problematic row is:

```
<div class="form-validation-text" *ngIf="!dynamicFilterFormGroup.get(formRow.formGroupName.formElem.name).valid && dynamicFilterFormGroup.get(formRow.formGroupName.formElem.name).touched">{{ 'formElem.validationText' | lang }}</div>
```

Getting:

```
DynamicTableComponent.html:11 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DynamicTableComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45258)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44270)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44593)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44593)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score -1):

Just use `?` to make some varibale as optional

```
<div class="form-validation-text" *ngIf="!dynamicFilterFormGroup.get(formRow.formGroupName.formElem?.name)?.valid && dynamicFilterFormGroup.get(formRow.formGroupName.formElem?.name)?.touched">{{ formElem?.validationText | lang }}</div>
```

Comment: every input has a name, the problem is, that because the two *ngFor I can't provide a proper path to the control in the get() method.

Comment: can u make a live demo(stackblitz) ?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use .get() twice. First get the formGroup outside, then get the inner one:

```
<div class="form-validation-text" *ngIf="!dynamicFilterFormGroup.get(formRow.formGroupName).get(formElem.name).valid && dynamicFilterFormGroup.get(formRow.formGroupName).get(formElem.name).touched">{{ formElem.validationText }}</div>
```